# How can I build with libcurl and not use the apt-get libraries?

Tags: linux, curl, makefile, shared-libraries, libcurl

Coming from a cushy Windows background, this building in linux is harder to understand, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

I have a c++ program that uses libcurl. It built fine on windows, but I must now port it to linux (specifically the raspberry pi). It uses the mime functions, so near-enough the latest version must be used. I've installed curl 7.62 by downloading it from *https://curl.haxx.se/download.html* and installing it as per the instructions at *https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html* to */home/pi/libraries/*.

I have a dummy localhost web-server up for testing. When I call `curl localhost` from the terminal, I get: `curl: (48) An unknown option was passed in to libcurl`. When building and running my program I get an `undefined symbol: curl_mime_init` at run-time. After some googling, this appears to be a version mis-match and I confirmed this by checking versions:
Calling `curl-config --version` gives: `libcurl 7.62.0`, but calling `curl --version` gives: `curl 7.62.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.52.1 <other stuff>...`.

I assume that my program and curl are both looking else-ware for libcurl, but **how can I specify the manually installed version of libcurl to g++, to my prog at run-time and to curl when calling from the terminal?**

My program's makefile:

```
all: obj/curltests.o obj/Utility.o obj/curl_handler.o bin/curltests

obj/Utility.o: src/Utility.cpp src/Utility.h
    g++ -g -c -pthread src/Utility.cpp -o obj/Utility.o

obj/curl_handler.o: src/curl_handler.cpp src/curl_handler.h
    g++ -g -c -pthread src/curl_handler.cpp -o obj/curl_handler.o

obj/curltests.o: src/curltests.cpp
    g++ -g -c -pthread src/curltests.cpp -o obj/curltests.o

bin/curltests: obj/curltests.o obj/Utility.o obj/curl_handler.o makefile
    g++ -Wall -g \
        -I src \
        -L/home/pi/libraries/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib -lboost_system \
        -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time \
        obj/Utility.o obj/curltests.o obj/curl_handler.o  \
        -L/home/pi/libraries/curl-7.62.0/lib -lcurl \
        -o bin/curltests
```

Not sure if this helps, but running `whereis libcurl.so` shows *libcurl[.la][.so]* in */usr/lib/* and *libcurl[.a][.la][.so]* in */usr/local/lib*, but none in */home/pi/libraries/curl-7.62.0/lib* as specified in the makefile above.

Comment: This should be enough, it's at runtime that you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Honestly, I'm not sure which path to add to it. I've added the one in the makefile, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You need to add at the beginning the path to your new library. Usual Linux stuff.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Then perhaps I am not building curl properly. I've added the root of the library, the libs folder and the folder above it for the sake of it and I've still got undefined symbol on curl mime

Comment: For the first error after "curl localhost", have you tried "curl 127.0.0.1" ?